# MVC3 @Ajax.Actionlink displaying new page instead of replacing targetupdateId

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

VS2010/.net4/MVC3 (MVC4 has the same problem)

I am trying to call an AJAX function in my project

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Display ALL Cbms results", "All" , "Cbms", new AjaxOptions()
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    UpdateTargetId = "divCbms",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
})
```

Controller code

```
public PartialViewResult All()
{
    List<cbms> model = cbms.GetAllCBMSData();
    return PartialView("_Cbms", model);
}
```

but instead of replacing the target div, a whole new page gets loaded.

I have referenced the unobtrusive script in the _layout page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>      
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have tried numerous solutions provided here, but none seem to work. 
Including:

- Update of jquery scripts to newest version (1.11.1 since I need to have backwards compatibility with old IE browsers)
- Solution below:

  ```
  <appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  ```
- Changing HttpMethod type to:

  ```
  @Ajax.ActionLink("<text here>", "All" , "<view name here>", new AjaxOptions()
  {
      HttpMethod = "POST",
      UpdateTargetId = "<div name here>",
      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
  })
  ```

I really have no idea how to solve this issue, I have also tried creating a whole new project (in MVC4) but this gives the same exact issue.

An inspection of the  request returns the following result:
[Ajax request details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN2iq.jpg)

Network inspection returns the following results:
[Ajax network header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf4P3.png)

Browsing to the URL provided ("http://localhost:58339/Cbms/All?X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest") works without issues. But this is not the format I want and thus does not solve my issue.

Comment: is your controller action is hitting or not???

Comment: The new page is being displayed, with the data on it, so the controller must be hit, yes. However, I want it to update a div section, not show a new page.

Comment: just give reference of 'jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js' js file at the ending of body tag or in footer in layout page..

Comment: Adding the reference of 'jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js' in the footer (also in the header or body) causes the link to not function anymore??

Comment: include it only once

Comment: @DaGrooveNL if the whole page is loading in div then make sure that the view you are loading is partial view not view , add ``@ { layout = null;}``

Comment: I changed the script to be referenced only once, but the link still does not work. I debugged and the method in the controller gets hit, data is being saved in variables, but apparently the new page is not being displayed anymore? So, the link itself functions, but visually does not display anything anymore.

Comment: can you show the real code of your

Comment: Let me edit, hang on.

Comment: As clarification, data is being retrieved (in variables) but will not visually display anymore. When I remove the unobtrusive script then a new page is being displayed (I understand that I the unobtrusive script is needed).

Comment: I've edited the post, do you need more information? Do you want me to show more code?

Comment: Adding "@layout = null;" in my partial view does not make any difference.

Comment: Moved the script reference back to the <head> section. Still no change.

Comment: I am beginning to think that it might be something with converting the XML to a useable format? Either that or the fact that the connection closes? See my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a different  section (with a different id), and tried updating that  section.
That worked (serious)!!!

I am totally blown away, how is this possible?? I really don't get it...

Answer (score 0):

Use as below

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Display ALL Cbms results", "All" , "Cbms", new AjaxOptions
{
      HttpMethod = "GET",
      UpdateTargetId = "divCbms",
      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace 
})
```

Updated

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Display ALL Cbms results", "All" , "Cbms", new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "divCbms"
})
```

Comment: Nothing happens. I click the link and nothing changes. Controller still gets hit though. Return Partialview is also being executed.

Comment: @DaGrooveNL Post HTML as well.

Comment: @DaGrooveNL where is the div in which you are trying to put data share that

Comment: It is the list view of my model. @model IEnumerable<databaseModel.cbms>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cbms Home";
}

<h2>cbmsIndex</h2> 

<div style="overflow:auto; width:inherit" id="divCbms">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>        
        etc...

Comment: try after remove style once

Comment: @AmitAgrawal No change, problem still persists.

Comment: can you send me html rendered code to identify the issue?

Comment: @AmitAgrawal http://pastebin.com/w1c9dWKh - I omitted some sensitive data in the display (the < > things)

Comment: @DaGrooveNL I got the issue.` data-ajax-update="#divCbms" ` it should be `data-ajax-update="divCbms" `.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal And how do I correct that? Editing it via the Mozilla Inspector to "divCbms" instead of "#divCbms" does not solve the issue.